# API Google Maps Marcador

Tags: php, javascript, google, maps

Boa noite srs.

Estou tentando usar um marcador para cada ponto vindo do banco de dados no código abaixo:
Neste código já existe o traçar da rota percorida usando a Lat e longitude recebidas do banco, só preciso que em cada inserção no mapa seja identificado com um marcador, além é claro da linha que o objeto percorreu​, que no caso esta funcionando.

Aqui existe a conexão e consulta na tabela..

```
while($RS= mysql_fetch_array($RSS)){
    $x = $x + 1;
    $kx .= "new google.maps.LatLng(".str_replace(",", ".", $RS["vl_latitude"]).", ".str_replace(",", ".", $RS["vl_longitude"])."),";

    if($RS["ig"] == "1"){$ig="LIGADA";}else{$ig="DESLIGADA";}
    if($x == 1){$pt = $pt . chr(91)."'INICIO: ".date("d/m/Y H:i:s", strtotime($RS["dt_hora"]))." - ".$RS["ds_posicao"]." | Ig: ".$ig."', ".str_replace(",", ".", $RS["vl_latitude"]).", ".str_replace(",", ".", $RS["vl_longitude"]).", ".$x."],";}
    $adata  = $RS["dt_hora"];
    if($RS["ig"] == "1"){$aig="LIGADA";}else{$aig="DESLIGADA";}
    //$aig  = $RS["ig"];
    $apos   = $RS["ds_posicao"];
    $alat   = $RS["vl_latitude"];
    $alng   = $RS["vl_longitude"];
}
$pt = $pt . chr(91)."'FIM: ".date("d/m/Y H:i:s", strtotime($adata))." - ".$apos." | Ig: ".$aig."', ".str_replace(",", ".", $alat).", ".str_replace(",", ".", $alng).", ".$x."],";
```

?>

Aqui continua com o arquivo em anexo (foto)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: qual erro está acontecendo?

Comment: Não está ocorrendo erro, até aí está tudo ok, traçando a linha conforme a consulta de latitude e longitude realizada acima, porém além de traçar a linha, preciso inserir um marcador em cada ponto com base no select acima. Ou seja terei centenas de pontos durante um dia em que o objeto percorreu alguns km.

Comment: Veja na imagem, preciso inserir marcadores como os quadrinhos na imagem que represente onde foi que o localizador enviou posição para o sistema

Answer (score 0):

[image: segue imagem para entender melhor o que estou tentando fazer.]
Veja se é possível compreender o que tenho tentando fazer. Obrigado.